# Change Location of Outgoing Link On Click

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to link to another page without displaying the real URL on hover or in the source code. I want `<a>` to redirect to `$newUrl;` even if there is another url defined in the `href=""`.

```
<?php $newUrl = "http://therealurl.com/folder/private.php" ?>
<a href="http://domain.com">Link</a>
```

So using the code above I want to replace `http://domain.com` with `<?php echo $newUrl; ?>` when the user clicks on the `<a>` because i never want it to be displayed to the user.

Is there a solution to target a specific anchor to do this? If not then every link on the page is fine I just want to do this in a way that the real URL is not displayed for privacy reasons.

Comment: Security through obscurity is never a good idea. Why do you want to hide it? Even if you "hide" your link anyone can still find out what it is, very easily, using Chrome's Dev tools for example.

Comment: There is many ways one is htaccess and other is jQuery onclick function change the href attr. Or may be you can find more.

Comment: @benpix i know its not 100% secure, i just need the url to display something different from where the page is going

Comment: @SunilPachlangia i know about the htaccess way, and jquery may be to much code for my purpose what other ways are there?

Comment: Another way would be to use a URL shortener service like bit.ly or something like that.

Comment: You don't want to code and you still want output?? Strange

Comment: @SunilPachlangia what?

Comment: @SunilPachlangia im trying ot keep the filesize down since its a mobile page. jquery is too heavy for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution.

```
 <?php $newUrl = "http://therealurl.com/folder/private.php"; ?>
 <script>
  $( document ).ready(function(){
  $( '#link' ).click(function(){
        var newLink = <?php echo json_encode($newUrl);?>;
        $(this).attr("href", newLink);
    });
  });
 </script>
 <a id="link" href="http://domain.com">Link</a>
```

Don't forget to include jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

If you have full access to the original link, you could use it as a redirect by setting a header in the destination script.

```
header("Location: yoururl.php);
```

This is the only quick easy solution that I can think of, as this one will not show the actual destination in the source code.

If you want to hide the link from the source code then any javascript methods won't work, to my knowledge.

You could also use ?page=get stuff to change where it sends the user, in order to make this script usable in multiple ways, just don't forget to manage your GET data safely.